# Solaris: where iostat information came from?

Tags: virtualbox, solaris

I do

`iostat -En`

and report a lot of dead disk(I have removed them)
format and cfgadm see one disk(I use one disk!)
so where those disk info came from?
How to remove?

Output of iostat

```
c0t1d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 52.43GB <52428799488 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 242 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 
sd4              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 17.18GB <17179868672 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 358 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 
sd5              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 27.92GB <27917286912 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 140 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 
sd6              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 27.92GB <27917286912 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 139 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 
sd7              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 27.92GB <27917286912 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 144 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 
sd8              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
Vendor: ATA      Product: VBOX HARDDISK    Revision: 1.0  Serial No:  
Size: 27.92GB <27917286912 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 193 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

Using `devfsadm -C` give..nothing.

Comment: have you tried to do a reconfiguration reboot? `reboot -- -r`

Comment: if reboot even without -- -r the devices disappear,but i want a solution without reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `devfsadm -C` should have done what you wanted.  If you use -Cv, you'll get verbose output.

You don't note your version of Solaris.  The older versions also had other scripts for creating the links for the various devices.  ie:  devlinks (?)

If you're running Solaris 11, try running:  `diskinfo`

Looking at your output, it appears you're using virtual box.  I've only run virtual box on Solaris, so I can't give much insight as to troubleshooting serving out and removing disks using virtual box with a Solaris guest.